# Movie review blog posts with view count, likes etc

Tags: sentiment-analysis

I started doing a research project for my final year and I need to analyze blog posts and extract common patterns from them.

For that I need blog post data where I can get the content with number of views, likes, comments, social media shares and etc.
I am mainly focusing movie and product reviews.

Are there any public datasets available for my requirements?

Comment: IMDB, The Internet Movie Database is available as a dump: ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/pub/misc/movies/database/. But read this short page first: http://www.imdb.com/interfaces. This datadump includes ratings. Longer reviews contributed by IMDB users are not included, you may have to scrape yourself.

Comment: this http://mx.daviesinc.com/qwait/metastor has alot of movies/rankings in json from tmdb api ex http://mx.daviesinc.com/qwait/metastor/blob/master/metadata/10000_BC.json