# Movie plots and reviews dataset

Tags: data-request, film, books

Is there any dataset with movie **plots and reviews** (not only rating)?

I have had a look at the existing dataset, but they contain only one of the two (i.e. only plots or only reviews).

I would be interested in similar datasets for books.

Comment: related? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/10179/1511

Comment: @philshem Not quite, as that look just a request for reviews and their metainformation. All the datasets linked in that post do not have or reviews or plots. E.g. the IMDB linked has plots and ratings but not reviews.